# CefSharp Chromium package Widevine support

Tags: c#, chromium, cefsharp

I am using CefSharpWpf v47
I will watch DRM protected content from my application. 
So I allow keeping signed between restart, allowed Flash, set chache pathes.

```
   static BrowserManager()
    {
        if (!Cef.IsInitialized)
        {
            var settings = new CefSettings
            {
                CachePath = @"cache",
                UserDataPath = @"usercache",
                LogFile = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "logs", "debug.log"),
            };
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("persist_session_cookies", "1");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-automatic-password-saving", "enable-automatic-password-saving");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-password-save-in-page-navigation", "enable-password-save-in-page-navigation");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-widevine-cdm", "1");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ppapi-flash-path", Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"pepflashplayer64_21_0_0_242.dll"));

            Cef.Initialize(
                cefSettings: settings, 
                shutdownOnProcessExit: true, 
                performDependencyCheck: true
            ); 
        }
    }
```

But not Netflix.com nor Amediateka.ru doesn't work. 
Netflix shows error 1204, and Amediateka crushes my application. 
When I try to explore Shaka player https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/demo/ it shows me Shake error. DRM.WRONG_KEYS()

Do i need to make my own CefSharp build with modified Chromium (enable some flags???) or there is a simplier solution?

Comment: `Netflix` requires `Proprietary Codecs` for which you need to obtain a license. Then you'd need to build `CEF` with `Proprietary Codec` support. Topic has been covered many times before, search for those key words and you should find info.

Comment: Thank you, for answer. But does it appliable to Shaka also?

Comment: I've never heard of it, you'll have to do your own research.